# Dynamic Programming Python path algorithm

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I'm a TA whose supposed to be better than my students at the homework, but there is one problem I can't seem to fix. Here's the outline:

> Input specification: the first line contains m, the highest street number. Note that there are m+1 total streets, from 0th street to mth street. The second line contains n, the highest avenue number. Note that there are n+1 total avenues, from 0th avenue to nth avenue. Next follow m+1 lines. The first of these lines contains values for 0th street. The next line contains values for 1st street. And so forth. Each line contains n values, with a space between values. Each value is either a 0 or 1. A 0 indicates that the block has been shoveled. A 1 indicates that the block has not yet been shoveled. The first value corresponds to the block between 0th avenue and 1st avenue. The next value corresponds to the block between 1st avenue and 2nd avenue. And so forth. Next follow n+1 lines. The first of these lines contains values for 0th avenue. The next line contains values for 1st avenue. And so forth. Each line contains m values, with a space between values. Each value is either a 0 or 1. A 0 indicates that the block has been shoveled. A 1 indicates that the block has not yet been shoveled. The first value corresponds to the block between 0th street and 1st street. The next value corresponds to the block between 1st street and 2nd street. And so forth. You may assume that n and m are both at most 1000.

So basically I'm trying to go from [0][0] on a 2D array to [n][m] where moving down and right are dictated by if two other arrays have a 1 or a 0 in that spot. Here's my code

## Author: Justin Haddock

## shovel.py

```
def initialize():
    #Generate variables
    f = open("test.txt", "r")
    streets = int(f.readline().strip())
    aves = int(f.readline().strip())
    streetsArray = []
    avesArray = []
    for x in range(streets+1):
        streetsArray.append([int(x) for x in f.readline().strip().split(" ")])

    for y in range(aves+1):
        avesArray.append([int(x) for x in f.readline().strip().split(" ")])
    streetsArray = rotate(streetsArray)
    findPath(streetsArray, avesArray)

def printArray(arr):
    for x in arr:
        print(x)


def rotate(arr):
    #Rotate the aves array to make it more usable
    rotated = list(zip(*reversed(arr)))
    rotated2 = list(zip(*reversed(rotated)))
    rotated3 = list(zip(*reversed(rotated2)))
    new = []
    for x in reversed(range(len(rotated3))):
        new.append(list(rotated3[x]))
    return new


def findPath(a, b):
    print("-----A------")
    printArray(a)
    print("-----B------")
    printArray(b)
    print("------------")
    print(len(b))
    dynArray = [[0]*len(a[0]) for x in range(len(b))]
    printArray(dynArray)
    print("------------")
    for x in range(0, len(dynArray)):
        for y in range(0, len(dynArray[0])):
            dynArray[x][y] = x+y
            if (x == 0 and y == 0):
                dynArray[x][y] = 0
            elif (x == 0):
                print(x,y)
                dynArray[x][y] = dynArray[x][y-1]+b[x][y-1]
            elif (y == 0):
                # print(x, y)
                dynArray[x][y] = dynArray[x-1][y] + b[x][0]
            else:
                dynArray[x][y] = min((dynArray[x][y-1]+a[x-1][y]), dynArray[x-1][y] + b[x][y-1])
    printArray(dynArray)
    print(dynArray[-1][-1])




if __name__ == "__main__":
    initialize()
```

I'm testing it against this test.txt file

```
7
4
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and my output is as follows (including the print statements)

```
-----A------
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
-----B------
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
------------
5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
------------
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
[3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
[4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
6
```

The answer is supposed to be 5 and I don't know where I'm going wrong here. Even when I do it by hand on a white board I still get 6. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand the input but what is the task? What does the number 5 signify? What are the other outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the minimum cost of 5 you must consider movement along the streets and
avenues in all 4 possible directions:

```
"""
ave_crossing[i][j] is the cost of crossing from avenue i to avenue i+1 (or vice versa) on street j
street_crossing[i][j] is the cost of crossing from street j to street j+1 (or vice versa) on avenue i
"""


def initialize():
    f = open("test.txt", "r")
    streets = int(f.readline().strip())
    aves = int(f.readline().strip())

    ave_crossing = []
    for x in range(streets + 1):
        ave_crossing.append([int(x) for x in f.readline().strip().split(" ")])
    ave_crossing = rotate(ave_crossing)

    street_crossing = []
    for y in range(aves + 1):
        street_crossing.append([int(x)
                                for x in f.readline().strip().split(" ")])
    return ave_crossing, street_crossing    

def printArray(arr):
    for x in arr:
        print(x)

def rotate(arr):
    return list(zip(*arr))

def findPath(ave_crossing, street_crossing):
    num_aves, num_streets = len(street_crossing), len(ave_crossing[0])
    dynArray = [[(ave + street) for street in range(num_streets)]
                for ave in range(num_aves)]
    printArray(dynArray)
    print("------------")

    queue = [(ave, street) for ave in range(num_aves)
             for street in range(num_streets)]

    for ave, street in queue:
        costs = []
        # consider the cost of all ways of arriving at (ave, street)
        if (street > 0):
            # start at (ave, street-1) and go to (ave, street)
            costs.append(dynArray[ave][street - 1] +
                         street_crossing[ave][street - 1])
        if (street < num_streets - 1):
            # start at (ave, street+1) and go to (ave, street)
            costs.append(dynArray[ave][street + 1] +
                         street_crossing[ave][street])
        if (ave > 0):
            # start at (ave-1, street) and go to (ave, street)
            costs.append(dynArray[ave - 1][street] +
                         ave_crossing[ave - 1][street])
        if (ave < num_aves - 1):
            # start at (ave+1, street) and go to (ave, street)
            costs.append(dynArray[ave + 1][street] + ave_crossing[ave][street])
        min_cost = min(costs, default=0)
        if (dynArray[ave][street] > min_cost):
            dynArray[ave][street] = min_cost
            # propagate the change in dynArray by recalculating dynArray
            # at neighboring locations
            neighbors = [(ave, street - 1), (ave, street + 1),
                         (ave - 1, street), (ave + 1, street)]
            neighbors = [(a, s) for a, s in neighbors if
                         0 <= a < num_aves and 0 <= s < num_streets]
            queue.extend(neighbors)

            print('dynArray[{}][{}] = {}'.format(
                ave, street, dynArray[ave][street]))
    printArray(dynArray)
    print(dynArray[-1][-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ave_crossing, street_crossing = initialize()
    print("-----ave_crossing------")
    printArray(ave_crossing)
    print("-----street_crossing------")
    printArray(street_crossing)
    print("------------")
    print(len(street_crossing))
    findPath(ave_crossing, street_crossing)
```

yields

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
[3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
[4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5]
```

for `dynArray` and a minimum cost of 5.

---

The code above evolved out of your code by applying the following three ideas:

- Use descriptive variable names. `x`,`y`,`a`,`b` are not descriptive. As a
  reader of your code, their meanings are a puzzle. Give yourself a week or two
  and the intent of your own code may become a puzzle to you too. Descriptive
  variable names will act like comments. They will help clarify intent. In place
  of `x` and `y` let's use `ave` and `street`, and in place of `a` and `b` let's
  (for the moment) continue using `streetsArray` and `avesArray` (but see
  below).
- It would be very helpful to state up front in the code that:

  ```
  streetsArray[i][j] is the cost of crossing from avenue i to avenue i+1 (or vice versa) on street j
  avesArray[i][j] is the cost of crossing from street j to street j+1 (or vice versa) on avenue i
  ```

  When this is stated explicitly, it becomes clearer that `streetsArray` and
  `avesArray` are perhaps not the most descriptive of variable names. Perhaps
  `ave_crossing` and `street_crossing` would be better. Note however, that this
  swaps the usage of `street` and `ave` in the variable names.
- Modify the algorithm to consider the possibility of moving "up" or to the
  "left" -- not just "down" and to the "right".